# Is a 610kb image too large for download in a smartphone app? (over mobile data network)

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm getting an image of size 610kb from an HTTP source and displaying it on my app main page  But I feel like its too large.  There are no alternatives - provider does not have any lower resolution images. It may eat away at users bandwidth if they refresh too often.  How should I handle this?

EDIT - its a live space image of earth updated every 30 seconds (but I programmed the app to update every hour - i.e. it caches the image to the phone so it wont update unless 1 or more hours has passed

BUT there is a refresh button, the user can force update whenever they want

Comment: Not enough information to answer. Can you live without the image? Can you cache it? Can you limit downloads to WiFi connections? What the heck is the image *for*?

Comment: ok added more info.  Yes I can live without it.  But its makes the app look nicer when its there.

Comment: put 1 hour as standard refresh time for 4G/3G and put 30 seconds when the user is on WiFi. The user must have an option (via a settings page) to make it 30 second on 4G/3G too since some users have a lot or unlimited data.

Comment: If it's really important, put a web server of your own in place that downloads the images on behalf of the phone, and compresses them further.

Comment: these are good recommendations.  thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never heard of such limitation in WP. As long as your app is in the foreground, it can download large files without problem. 610 kb isn't a big deal and it can be downloaded in a matter of seconds.

What you should pay attention to, however, is to download your image and do any heavy post-processing asynchronously (in a background thread). Also, make sure that the user is alerted that a download is in progress so that they can wait for it.